# MySQL returned an empty result set when inserting multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmWgG.png)I am new to PHP and Mysql. i am trying to create a quiz project where multiple questions in a quiz will be inserted into the database once. How can i go about it. I have searched for solutions here and i tried using foreach. i am not having errors but it is not uploading
here is my form

```html
<form class="quiz-questions">
    <h1>Title Of Quiz</h1>
    
    <?php 
        for($counter = 1; $counter <= $_SESSION['quiz_no']; $counter++)
        {
            echo "<div class='quiz-left'>";
            echo "<div>";
            echo "<label for='textarea' class='sn-quiz'>$counter</label><textarea name='question[]' class='textarea' id='example-three' placeholder='Enter the Question' cols='60' rows='3' ></textarea>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<div class='option-tag'>";
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='op1[]' value='optionA'>";
            echo "<input type='text' name='optionA[]' placeholder='optionA'>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<div class='option-tag'>";
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='op1[]' value='optionB'>";
            echo "<input type='text' name='optionB[]' placeholder='optionB'>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<div class='option-tag'>";
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='op1[]' value='optionC'>";
            echo "<input type='text' name='optionC[]' placeholder='optionC'>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<div class='option-tag'>";
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='op1[]' value='optionD'>";
            echo "<input type='text' name='optionD[]' placeholder='optionD'>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
        ?>

    
    <input type="submit" name="insert_quiz" class="btn-primary btn btn-lg" placeholder="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

and here is my submit code

```html
<?php 
 if(isset($_POST['insert_quiz'])) {
     
     $quiz_add_id = $_SESSION['quiz_id'];
     $count = $_SESSION['quiz_no'];
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_POST as $val) {
        $question = $_POST['question'][$i];
        $optionA = $_POST['optionA'][$i];
        $optionB = $_POST['optionB'][$i];
        $optionC = $_POST['optionC'][$i];
        $optionD = $_POST['optionD'][$i];
        $op1 = $_POST['op1'][$i];
        
        $query = "INSERT INTO quizzes (quiz_add_id, quiz_question, quiz_option_A, quiz_option_B, quiz_option_C, quiz_option_D, quiz_option_correct)";

        $query .= "VALUES ('{$quiz_add_id}', '{$question}', '{$optionA}','{$optionB}','{$optionC}','{$optionD}', '{$op1}')";

        $create_quiz_query = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        $i++;
      } 
  if(!$create_quiz_query ){
      die('QUERY FAILED' . mysqli_error($connection));

}
     
 }
?>
```

Comment: var_dump($_POST); ?

Comment: print query and see what was the issue all values come or not and run query in mysql

Comment: Default form method is GET, not POST.

Comment: you should do a loop like `for($i=0; $i<count( $_POST['question']);$i++)`

Comment: please i dont understand @D

Comment: _sidenote_: please change to prepared statements. Your code is unsecure, open to sql injection.

Comment: @Jeff i have tried that method also but it is not still inserting

Comment: Don't write SQL with embedded PHP variables, instead use an SQL prepared statement using ? markers and pass your data as parameters to the execute function, this will take care of any character escaping.

Comment: @Timi, place this line in the beginning of your php file: var_dump($_POST); and post output here. Also as Jon Stirling said, your form doesn't have method, you should make your method to POST

Comment: You claim you have no errors, but have you tried showing them? Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script and report back what it spits out.

Comment: thanks. it is posting now @D.Dimitrov